# MacOS : crypt all web traffic within a ssh tunnel

Tags: mac, security, ssh, tunnel

I have set up a ssh tunnel to communicate with internet.

This allows me to ensure my data are crypted and can not be stealed if I am using a non-trusted connection.

I add a sock proxy in connection setting on my Mac OS X sustem.

But my question is the following.

How force all the traffic, even the application that doesn't handle proxies connection to use my ssh tunnel ?

Is that possible ? If it is not, is a VPN connection should be able to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

[sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle) ([Mac binary](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle/tree/sshuttle-0.51-macos-bin)) is said to do exactly this, and have better performance than ssh SOCKS by avoiding TCP-over-TCP, too. I haven't used it myself, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think SSHTunnel should be the software you are looking for.

http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/networking_security/sshtunnel.html

It allows encapsulation of different network access into SSH tunnels, wrapped with a easy to use interface.

Or else of course you can consider VPN-based implementation.

Ask if you want more details on VPNs...

Comment: I tryed to use sshtunnel, but i am not convinced... I didn't found how to encapsulate all my network traffic within the ssh tunnel. I really want to force the traffic to go throw the ssh tunnel. If a ssh tunnel is not able to do that, does a VPN could do that ?

Comment: i think sshtunnel should fit your need. anyways, if you use VPN of course it will force all traffic there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's available on Mac, but I use proxychains with LD_PRELOAD to accomplish this on other platforms.  There's a patch to compile it yourself here: http://chrootlabs.org/bgt/proxychains_osx.html